# How to get the values inside an array of some mongoose schema?

Tags: arrays, logging, mongoose, schema

```
    const test2 = new Writing ({
          title: "Suvra",
          content: "Testing the db"
        },
        {
          title: "John",
          content: "testing again"
        });
        
        const test = new User ({
          email: "Suvra's test",
          password: "This is a test",
          userID: "1234",
          userName: "suvra1234",
          yourWriting: [test2]
        });
        
        
        
          console.log(test);
```

After running this code, I'm just getting the first element of the array like this inside my console. I'm not getting what is the wrong happening with the code.
Inside the log I want to log all the element inside the array of `yourWriting` inside `test`. I don't know exactly what to do. I have tried most of the combination of parenthesis.
And yes, I have already declared the schemas of `Writing` and `User` like exactly below code. And `yourWriting` as an array inside `User` schema.

```
{
  _id: 5efdb1285f9dc62cf025444a,
  email: "Suvra's test",
  password: 'This is a test',
  userID: '1234',
  userName: 'suvra1234',
  yourWriting: [
    {
      _id: 5efdb1285f9dc62cf025444b,
      title: 'Suvra',
      content: 'Testing the db'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Writing` and `User` schema here.

Comment: Because your Writing Schema is just taking the first argument and hence it just has first element. Kindly log the value of test2 before passing to test.